# How to avoid SQL performs clustered index scan

Tags: sql-server, indexing, azure-sql-database, ef-core-3.1

I have used EF Core (3.1) to create a database (on AZURE).
Amongst other tables I have 2 related tables that are used the most for both frequent storing and retrieving.
A short code similar to what I use is shown here:

```
    public class ParentEntity
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public int PlaceID { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
        public IList<ChildEntity> ChildEntities { get; set; }
    }


    public class ChildEntity
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; }
        public ParentEntity ParentEntity { get; set; }
        public long ParentEntityID { get; set; }
    }

    public class ExampleDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ParentEntity> ParentEntities { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ChildEntity> ChildEntities { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ParentEntity>()
                .HasIndex(p => new { p.PlaceID, p.DateTime })
                .IsUnique();
            modelBuilder.Entity<ChildEntity>()
                .HasIndex(c => c.ParentEntityID);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ParentEntity>()
                .HasMany(p => p.ChildEntities)
                .WithOne(c => c.ParentEntity)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

    }

    public class DBUser
    {
        ExampleDBContext _context;
        private void Foo()
        {
            // The following call have been observed to take between 2 seconds and 4 minutes.
            var parents = _context.ParentEntities.Where(p => p.PlaceID == 1
                && p.DateTime > new DateTime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
                && p.DateTime < new DateTime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0))
                .Include(p => p.ChildEntities);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that it sometimes takes a long time to carry out the `DBUser.Foo()` method.
When I run a query using SSMS like the following (that I just guess is somewhat similar to what EF Core does):

```
SELECT p.ID, p.DateTime, c.ID, c.Value
FROM ChildEntities AS c
LEFT JOIN ParentEntities AS p ON c.ParentEntityID = p.ID
WHERE p.DateTime > '2020-01-01 00:00:00' AND p.DateTime < '2020-01-01 00:01:00' AND p.PlaceID = 1;
```

With "Include Actual Excecution Plan" I can se that the majority of the time is spent using a

> Clustered Index scan (Clustered) Cost: 59% 0:03:52

on the `[ChildEntities].[PK_ChildEntities]` (with a predicate looking like this `PROBE([Bitmap1003],[MyDatabase].[dbo].[ChildEntities].[ParentEntityID],N'[IN ROW]')`). Then there is also quite some cost used on

> Parallelism (Repartition Streams) Cost: 19%

> Hash Match (Inner Join) Cost: 22% 0:03:56

Looking at `sys.dm_db_missing_index_details` system view, it reports a missing index for `ChildEntities` with equality_columns: `ParentEntityID` and inequality_conlumns: `NULL` indicating to me that there is no index for that, even though I have stated that in my `ExampleDBContext` and SSMS show a `IX_ChildEntities_ParentEntityID (Non-Unique, Non-Clustered`).

Currently there are about 1.3 million rows in ParentEntities and 7 million rows in ChildEntities in the database (about 5 Children to each Parent).

Am I doing something obviously stupid or wrong? Is there something I could do to improve performance? (it would be nice to have a steady performance of just a couple of seconds instead of minutes) I would guess that a Index seek would be more performant than a Clustered Index Scan (that I understand as a complete table scan).

EDIT 2021-02.09:

My "real" ef query a tiny bit different:

```
    _context.ParentEntities.AsNoTracking()
                .Where(p => p.PlaceID == 1
                && p.DateTime > new DateTime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
                && p.DateTime < new DateTime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0))
                .Include(p => p.ChildEntities);
```

EF Core SQL query:

```
SELECT [p].[ID], [p].[DateTime], [p].[PlaceID], [c].[ID], [c].[Value], [c].[ParentEntityID] 
FROM [ParentEntities] AS [p] 
LEFT JOIN [ChildEntities] AS [c] ON [p].[ID] = [c].[ParentEntityID] 
WHERE (([p].[PlaceID] = 1) 
    AND ([p].[DateTime] >= '2021-02-08T00:00:00.0000000')) 
    AND ([p].[DateTime] <= '2021-02-08T00:01:00.0000000') 
ORDER BY [p].[ID], [c].[ID]
```

Using SSMS I scripted out create table as follows:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ParentEntities](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DateTime] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [PlaceID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ParentEntities] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ParentEntities]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ParentEntities_Places_PlaceID] FOREIGN KEY([PlaceID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Places] ([ID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ParentEntities] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ParentEntities_Places_PlaceID]
GO
```

and the index as follows:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ParentEntities_PlaceID_DateTime] ON [dbo].[ParentEntities]
(
    [PlaceID] ASC,
    [DateTime] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: You can extract the ACTUAL query plan from the system tables rather than guessing at what EF has translated your code into. It may not be exactly what you think.   It would also be useful for us to see what the table and indexes that your created actually are. Script out those definitions as well and then you'll get some more targeted advice

Comment: @MartinCairney thanks for the comment. I tried to expand on what you suggested.

Comment: How selective is PlaceID? How many values? If it's not selective, then reverse the index. Use the DateTime column first and PlaceID second. Also, naming columns after data types and reserved words just makes programming & maintaining the db a pain in the bottom. Unrelated to the performance problem, but I couldn't help but point it out.

Comment: @GrantFritchey what do you mean by selective? There are less than five (5) places at the moment. Does not selective means few values?

Comment: selective means basically the opposite of that - if there are many distinct values, then the odds of having a where clause with an equality predicate filtering out all of the values is higher and thus the predicate is "more selective".  If you only have 5 distinct values, it is likely not selective, in general, so your index with placeid as the first value will work but may or may not be as effective as having the datetime be first.

Comment: Let's imagine there are 1 million rows in the table. And there are 5 different places evenly distributed. Any given query is only going to get down to 200,000 rows out of the 1 million when you specify a place. The most efficient way to get that data is a scan. That's why I'd reverse the index columns. You'll get more filtering, probably, depending on the data, and therefore better performance.